# How to pass a value for useState hook from another component in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I have two components:

**Parent.js**

```
import { useState } from "react";

function Parent() {
    const [showHideContent, setShowHideContent] = useState("none");

    return (
        <div style={{ display: showHideContent }}>
            Some content here...
        </div>
    );
}
```

**Child.js**

```
function Child() {
    return (
        <button>
            Show/Hide Content
        </button>
    );
}
```

I want to pass two values **none** and **block** *(one value at a time)* through `setShowHideContent` of *Parent component* using `Show/Hide Content` button of *Child component*.

How to do this?

***NOTE:** These two components are saved in the same folder but in two different files.*

These two component are rendered by `App.js`.

```
<Route path="/content">
    <Menu /> {/* rendering in LEFT */}
    <div className="content-flexbox">
        <Parent /> {/* rendering in CENTER */}
        <Child /> {/* rendering in RIGHT */}
    </div>
    <Footer /> {/* rendering in BOTTOM */}
</Route>
```

Comment: Is the `Child` component being rendered by the `Parent` component? What have you tried? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: No, the `Child` component not being rendered by the `Parent` component.

Comment: Please update and show us how the two components relate and what you expect the interaction to be.

Comment: You should probably rename those components because they are neither Child or Parent to each other. Are you asking: "How can I click a button in Child that will hide/show Parent"?

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience caused due to component's name.
And, yes, you got my point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you want the `Child` component to simply toggle the `display` value of some content in the `Parent` component.

As you've defined them though they are not parent-child, but rather they are siblings. As such if they need to share state/behavior, then the solution is to lift state up to a common ancestor, `App` in this case.

```
<Route path="/content">
  <Menu />
  <div className="content-flexbox">
    <Parent /> // <-- siblings
    <Child />  // <-- siblings
  </div>
  <Footer />
</Route>
```

See: [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

Move the `showHideContent` state and updater into the parent `App` component, pass down the `showHideContent` state to `Parent` and the `toggleVisibility` callback to the `Child`.

```
function Parent({ showHideContent }) {
  return <div style={{ display: showHideContent }}>Some content here...</div>;
}

function Child({ onClick }) {
  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={onClick}>
      Show/Hide Content
    </button>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const [showHideContent, setShowHideContent] = React.useState("none");

  const toggleVisibility = () =>
    setShowHideContent((value) => (value === "none" ? "block" : "none"));

  return (
    ...
    <Route path="/content">
      <Menu />
      <div className="content-flexbox">
        <Parent showHideContent={showHideContent} />
        <Child onClick={toggleVisibility} />
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </Route>
    ...
  );
}
```

[image: Edit how-to-pass-a-value-for-usestate-hook-from-another-component-in-reactjs]

Comment: `Lifting State Up` is the perfect solution, don't know why its down votes

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass values as prop to child component.
Call your child component inside parent component and pass value

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Child from "//your path";

function Parent() {
const [showHideContent, setShowHideContent] = useState("none");

return (

    <div style={{ display: showHideContent }}>
       <Child showHide={showHideContent}/>
    </div>
);
```

}
Now in your child component

```
function Child({showHide}) {
return (
    <button>
        {showHide}
        Show/Hide Content
    </button>
);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

1. You can pass an inline function as prop from parent to child like this.

```
function Parent(){
   const [showHideContent, setShowHideContent] = useState("none");
   return (
    <Child onButtonClicked={(toValue) => setShowHideContent(toValue)} />
   )
}


function Child({ onButtonClicked }) {
    return (
        <button onClick={onButtonClicked} >
            Show/Hide Content
        </button>
    );
}
```

2. Pass down exact state modifier with same name

```
function Parent(){
   const [showHideContent, setShowHideContent] = useState("none");
   return (
    <Child setShowHideContent={setShowHideContent} />
   )
}

//or with prop speading
function Parent(){
   const [showHideContent, setShowHideContent] = useState("none");
   return (
    <Child {...{setShowHideContent}} />
   )
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Include your `Child` component in your `Parent` component and pass hooks as props

```
import { useState } from "react";
// import the child component
function Parent() {
    const [showHideContent, setShowHideContent] = useState("none");
    return (
        <div style={{ display: showHideContent }}>
            Some content here...
            <Child showHideContent={showHideContent}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

And use them in your child components

```
function Child({showHideContent}) {
    return (
        <button>
{showHideContent}
            Show/Hide Content
        </button>
    );
}
```

Another way of doing the same is by using `Context` API:

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext